# Set a delay for sending emails (php mail or via cake php)

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm using this code to send emails via a website programmed in Cakephp.

```
$email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
$email->to(array($user['email'] => $user['first_name']." ".$user['last_name']));
$email->emailFormat('both');
$email->from(array('info@domain.nl' => 'Domain'));
$email->subject('Registratie domain.nl');  
$email->template('registration_mail');
$email->viewVars(array('user' => $user));
$email->send();
```

How can I set a delay of 5 minutes before the system sends out this e-mail?
In cake php: app\config\email.php I find the settings used to send this email. I changed timeout to 300 but the mail is send < 30 seconds after registration.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why no use `sleep(300)` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito if a user navigates away from current page after triggering this sleep function then email will never get sent which is not something the OP would want I assume.

Comment: I don't think so, just in case set `ignore_user_abort(1)`

Comment: I guess you want to schedule emails to get delivered later, rather than introduce a delay per-se. I'm not sure if CakePHP offers the feature natively but it shouldn't be difficult to do it yourself with a `scheduled_emails` table, a `send_at` column and a cron job.

Comment: "timeout" does not mean delay - it's the time allowed to connect to the (email) server before abandoning the connection attempt. There is no code in the question attempting to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reactions, i will try to do it with a mysql table and a cronjob

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the cakephp-queue plugin of dereuromark